# Pyinstaller - FileNotFoundError when running exe on different PC

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to generate an .exe file from a Python script I made for converting a PDF into a dataframe that can be manipulated and outputted as a PDF again.

I originally had an issue with tabula not working with pyinstaller, but managed to edit the spec file to solve the issue. However, now I'm dealing with a FileNotFoundError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "room_list.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "tabula\io.py", line 314, in read_pdf
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'room_list.pdf'
[8608] Failed to execute script 'room_list' due to unhandled exception!
```

I do not have this issue on the PC that I ran pyinstaller on. When I transferred the exe to another PC and tried to run the program using the same file directory setup (desktop with room_list.pdf file), I got the above error. The room_list.pdf file is present where it should be, so I don't know why it's saying that no such file or directory exists.

I did run PyInstaller on a Windows 11 PC and the PC is Windows 10. Not sure if that could be an issue.

Here's the Python code:

```
import tabula as tb
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

df_list = tb.read_pdf('room_list.pdf', pages='all')

concat_list = []
for df in df_list:
    new_df = df.iloc[3:]
    new_df.columns = df.iloc[2]
    concat_list.append(new_df)

df_all = pd.concat(concat_list)
df_all.dropna(inplace=True)

def stay_over_status(row):
    if row['Occ Status'] == 'In-House':
        return 'X'
    else:
        return ' '

def check_out_status(row):
    if row['Occ Status'] == 'Due-Out':
        return 'X'
    else:
        return ' '

df_all['S/O'] = df_all.apply(stay_over_status, axis=1)
df_all['C/O'] = df_all.apply(check_out_status, axis=1)
df_all['OUT'] = ''

result = df_all.drop(columns=['Room Type', 'Occ Status', 'Condition', 'Guest Name', 'Arrives', 'Departs'])

fig, ax =plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
the_table = ax.table(cellText=result.values,colLabels=result.columns,loc='center', colWidths=[0.1 for x in result.columns], cellLoc='center')

pp = PdfPages("maid_list.pdf")
pp.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
pp.close()

# os.startfile("maid_list.pdf", "print")
```

**Possible solution:**

I experimented with a virtual copy of Windows 11, where I faced the same problem I described above. I had more freedom to work around with things, so I tried several different solutions. I put the full path directory specific for the PC. Instead of 'room_list.pdf' I tried C:\Users\User\Desktop\room_list.pdf'. That seemed to solve the FileNotFoundError for room_list.pdf, but I ran into another error. I forgot to note down what it was, but it had to do with tabula and requiring Java. Another post online mentioned installing Java to resolve this issue, which I did. Error was gone, but the maid_list.pdf was not being generated. Again, I went back and put the full directory specific to the virtual machine Desktop directory. This solved the problem, and I was able to get the maid_list.pdf without error.

I will eventually deploy this on the other PC I wanted this work on and will update this, but I'm assuming this will now work. I was hoping that I would not have to install Java or any program in the first place, but if there is no other alternative I will end up just doing that. If there is another way of converting the PDF to a Dataframe without the use of tabula and Java, I would love to hear about it. I'd also like to avoid creating a new exe every time I need to deploy this on another PC that has a different user account folder. If someone has a solution to this, I would greatly appreciate that too. One of the main reasons I went about trying to create an exe file was so that I could easily deploy this on multiple computers without the need of having to install and configure different things.

Comment: have you hard coded the path to the file?

Comment: If you installed pyinstaller on venv and then compiled to exe using this pyinstaller then pyinstaller would expect the base interpreter  to be located on the same path on the other pc

Comment: Yes, I did have use a venv when installing pyinstaller. I assumed that pyinstaller would negate this issue though? I wanted the exe file created so that I could use the program on a computer without having to install Python or configure anything on the other PC. The file path within the program is just "room_list.pdf" and I'm running the exe in the same directory that room_list.pdf is located in. I tried this on my main PC and it worked fine regardless of what directory I put the exe and room_list.pdf in, as long as they both were in the same directory.

Comment: Have you tried using pathlib? With `pathlib.Path(".") /  'room_list.pdf'`